# Use regex to match the first occurrence of a letter in each word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace the first occurrence of “I” in a word other than at the start of the word with “ee”. I'm using java.

This should change the phrase

```
INFINITY IS GIANT.
```

To:

```
INFeeNITY IS GeeANT.
```

So far, my code has gone through several revisions. One is:

```
replaceAll("(?<=[^I*])\\BI", "ee");
```

That is using lookbehind, I think. Help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in the OP `\\BI` finds the first `I` character which is not at the start of the word - if the regular expression then matches the rest of the word, using `(?:\\B.)*` or `.*?\\b`, then it won't match a second `I` in the same word.

```
"INFINITY IS GIANT".replaceAll( "\\BI((?:\\B.)*)", "ee$1");
"INFINITY IS GIANT".replaceAll( "\\BI(.*?\\b)", "ee$1");
```

Will both result in:

```
INFeeNITY IS GeeANT
```

It even works if you have accents in the text:

```
"IŇFINIŦŶ IS ĞIANŤ".replaceAll( "\\BI((?:\\B.)*)", "ee$1");
"IŇFINIŦŶ IS ĞIANŤ".replaceAll( "\\BI(.*?\\b)", "ee$1");
```

Both output:

```
IŇFeeNIŦŶ IS ĞeeANŤ
```

**Alternatively**

Using `\\b(.(?:\\B.)*?)\\BI` can match from the start of the word to the first `I`:

```
"INFINITY IS GIANT".replaceAll( "\\b(.(?:\\B.)*?)\\BI", "$1ee");
```

Outputs:

```
 INFeeNITY IS GeeANT
```

Comment: +1, that's much simpler than my solution. You can even further [simplify](http://ideone.com/2wSNUz) it to `\BI(\w*)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about accented letters, this pattern will do the trick:

```
\b([a-zA-Z][a-hj-zA-HJ-Z]*)[iI]
```

Replace it with `$1ee`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS0qF1/2)

It matches the first letter of a word (`\b[a-zA-Z]`) then any numer of letters except `I` (`[a-hj-zA-HJ-Z]*`), then `I`.

If you have to deal with accented letters, the pattern has to change somewhat:

```
(?<!\p{L})(\p{L}(?:(?![iI])\p{L})*)[iI]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH5oD2/6)

Here, I used `\p{L}` which means *any Unicode letter*, but had to write `(?![iI])\p{L}` to mean *any Unicode letter except `I`*. I also replaced `\b` with `(?<!\p{L})` to make sure I get Unicode support.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes the syntax for this is `[A-Z-[I]]` but it's [not supported in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) - only a few regex flavors support that AFAIK.

Comment: I would probably do `(?<!^)(?<!\b)(\w*?)I(\w*)`

Comment: @hwnd If I am not mistaken `(?<!\b)` is the same as `\B` (negation of `\b`) which should also handle case `(?<!^)`

Comment: @hwnd indeed, `\BI(\w*)` is much simpler (when used with `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`). I should stop posting patterns at late night ;-)

Comment: @Pshemo, indeed.. I was over-thinking the matter.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski "*`\BI(\w*)` is much simpler (when used with `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`)*"  `\b` (and `\B`) support Unicode even without `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` class. Example `"aćać".replaceAll("\\Ba", "x")`->`aćxć` so as you see even without `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag `(?U)` `a` in the middle will treat `ć` as correct word-character.

Comment: @Pshemo indeed, but you still need `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` for that `\w` in the pattern. This Unicode support discrepancy between `\b` and `\w` surprises me a lot TBH.

Comment: Yes if we would need to also use `\w` then `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` is needed. I am just wondering if we really need `\w` here. Maybe `\S` would be simpler (it would also handle `'` in our words, but this would depend on what input OP expect).